# Difference between (?=.*foo\b) and (?=.*foo)\b

Tags: regex

What's difference between these two patterns:

- `(?=.*foo\b)`
- `(?=.*foo)\b`

Is it a difference in performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two patterns mean something different. In particular, the first one will not match `blah foobar`, but the second one will.

The contents of a zero-width positive lookahead assertion (`(?= … )`) are *not* consumed by the assertion. Any text following the assertion starts matching at the same point that the regex was searching at before the assertion was checked.

As such, the regular expression `(?=.*foo\b)` matches any string where the string `foo` appears right before a word boundary, but `(?=.*foo)\b` matches any string which contains `foo` and starts at a word boundary. The second of these is a pretty weird thing to look for, and is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Ugh, frustrated that one went over my head. +1

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in where is checks for the word boundary: in the first one, the word boundary must be after `.*foo`, but in the second, it must be before `.*foo`. See these two examples:

1. [`(?=.*foo\b)`](http://regex101.com/r/iV0sS4)
2. [`(?=.*foo)\b`](http://regex101.com/r/bU0dN1)